# Creating a table of workers with first shift last week

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

I am trying to extract a list of workers who had their first shift during last week.

Right now, my SQL works if I put a specific worker with a first shift in last week in my where clause (`WHERE c.temp_nr ='XXXX'`), but when I remove that clause, it just timeout

```
SELECT MIN(p.start_date), CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS 'c.fullname', c.temp_nr
FROM contactstable c 
LEFT JOIN projectlines p on c.temp_nr = p.candidate_number 
WHERE c.temp_nr ='XXXX' and c.contact_type = 'Candidate' 
HAVING MIN(p.start_date) between DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL (dayofweek(CURDATE())+6) 
DAY ) 
AND DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL (dayofweek(CURDATE())) 
DAY )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY c.temp_nr`

```
SELECT MIN(p.start_date), CONCAT(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) AS 'c.fullname', c.temp_nr
FROM contactstable c
LEFT JOIN projectlines p on c.temp_nr = p.candidate_number
WHERE c.contact_type = 'Candidate'
GROUP BY c.temp_nr
HAVING
    MIN(p.start_date)
        between
            DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (dayofweek(CURDATE())+6) DAY)
            AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE() , INTERVAL (dayofweek(CURDATE())) DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, but the query takes around 4 minutes.. Do you know what gives?

Comment: @Frederik you should add indexes to you tables, on `c.temp_nr` & `p.candidate_number`.